# an error in runining canopy example in mahout

Tags: maven, cluster-analysis, mahout

I want to run canopy example in mahout, but I am getting error:

> Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
> Running on hadoop, using /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
> MAHOUT-JOB: /usr/local/mahout-distribution-0.7/examples/target/mahout-examples-0.7-> job.jar
> Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/Closeables
> at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.loadProperties(MahoutDriver.java:214)
> at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:98)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
> at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
> at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.io.Closeables
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
> ... 7 more

in case, there is guava-r09.jar in "/usr/local/mahout-distribution-0.7/examples/target/dependency" that including com/google/common/io/Closeables class and its dependency is in pom.xml.

what can I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Hadoop and Mahout is a mess. You are probably in **jar hell**.

I don't think it is actually worth to try a lot. Unless you have Google scale data, a non-Mapreduce implementation will likely be **much faster**. That is: as long as your data fits into memory of a single node, prefer a single-node solution.

In my experiments, a Mahout cluster with 10-15 CPUs would be about 5x slower than a good single CPU implementation. Because all this "framework" and the disk-oriented operation of Hadoop and Mahout come at a substantial cost. So, if your data isn't on the size of terabytes, don't use it.

Now to a more precise answer:

You are in a *distributed* world. It is not sufficient if this .jar file is avilable on your computer.
Due to the design of Hadoop, it must actually be *uploaded* to every host that participates in your computation. The `mahout` command is supposed to take care of this (identifying and uploading all required .jar files), but sometimes it fails to get the classpath right. And unfortunately, the process is a mess and hard to understand or debug.

> Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Take this warning seriously. What is the *current* way of getting the classpath right?